# Can't type array in react state?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array in state

```
state = {
        array: [],
    };
```

Later I do this

```
method = (el): void => {
        const {array} = this.state;
        const includesEl = array.includes(el);
}
```

And I'm getting an error

```
 Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

I type state interface like this

```
export interface State{
    array: any[],
}
```

Should I type the state in state declaration as well? Because I assume the error is coming from the face that I'm setting `array` initially to `[]`

Comment: Any online code sample of your question? Since info may be lacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
state: State = {
    array: []
}
```

Comment: It works!
Strange because I already have it like this

```class Component extends React.Component<Props, State> ```

Comment: Here is what I found:
This is because they work in two different ways, the 2nd generic type parameter will allow this.setState() to work correctly, because that method comes from the base class, but initializing state inside the component overrides the base implementation so you have to make sure that you tell the compiler that you're not actually doing anything different.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a specific type of `Argument`.

```
method = (el: `TYPE`): void => {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this,

```
method = (el: []): void => {
        const {array} = this.state;
        const includesEl = array.includes(el);
}
```

or may be add this to state like `state = { array : any as []}`

Comment: ```state = { array : any[]}``` gives ```'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here```

Comment: @Allan or use it with as any[] like Jai suggested